# What is the difference between Devas and Asuras?

Tags: history, asuras, gods, terminology

Devas are the benevolent and asuras are manevolent. Asuras used to take captive of Devas. Other than this, any historical comparison to devas and asuras?
What are the meanings of these terms?

Comment: What do you mean by "historical meaning"?

Comment: I have read article saying that the people of Assyria as Asura. What is ur opinion about that? Similar to asura ,does Devas refer to any kind of people historically?

Comment: **Any historical comparison to any kind of people.For ex: I read in an article that Asura- refers to the people of Assyria** You should add this in ur question itself. It will then be clear what ur actual question is.