# About Devas and Asuras

Tags: vedas, history, asuras, gods

I have read an article saying that the Asuras are historically referring to the people of Assyria and so Devas may also be refer to some kind of people historically. What are your thoughts about this. If my case is true, then to whom does Devas may refer to?

Comment: Please link the article if possible.

Comment: So you want to know if Devas can also be linked with some particular group of people living on earth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Devas and Asuras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/what-is-the-difference-between-devas-and-asuras)

Comment: @iammilind It is not duplicate. OP wants correlation between people living on earth to Asuras and devas.

Comment: *"What are your thoughts about this"* @TheDestroyer -- technically this statement makes it an opinion based. However, should we ignore that. Even in that case it's duplicate. *Deva*-s and *Asura*-s are already explained in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20778/1049), which is linked to the linked duplicate. Since it's clear who are *Deva*-s and *Asura*-s, it's redundant to ask their historical context with respect to places on earth. Let's see what other people feel about this Qn.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/25220495?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents , this is the book I was referring to.... I think this correlation is possible. I think Asuras as Assyrians and Devas as Isralites. What u people think?

Comment: @Nadhiya This is western speculation and it has no proofs. Devas and Asuras live in other realms which are not visible to human eye.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Asur and Deva were historical figures. RigVeda described both. Asur belonged to an earlier age whose genesis is not dealt with in detail. But the genesis of Deva is more than explicit. The real problem lies in the interpretation of RigVeda and understanding the real historical themes it contains. In recent times many scholars have started to treat RigVeda  as historical document in order to describe history of ancient India often refer a historical event - "the battle of ten kings" (ref. RV.7.18 (1-25). But they have to go a long way to shade away the connotations held by later scripture about RigVeda which are often contradictory to RigVedic dictum.
Not only Assyria, but entire old world namely Sumer, Mesopotamia, Canaan, Persia, Greek and even Egpt seem to be inter-related and influenced by a comman single source and our RigVeda stands to be closure of that. But we have to reveal RigVeda in proper manner discarding the notion later scripture forces upon us that they are the only way to go up to RigVeda for we can not understand 'Asura' properly if we approach RigVeda with it's meaning as 'Rakshas'. To add your information, there is was a great city ' Asur' in ancient Mesopotamia.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your reply. do you have any proof for your theory? if yes, then please share it with me.

i think Devas are the common term used to refer the Isralites and Asuras are the people who oppressed them. I don't have any secular proof for this. what did you think about this?

Comment: Your thinking is in a right way but a vague parallel. I am doing research precisely on these topics and going to write book so can't share details of proof. Bit I will try to answer your queries if you post them on this site. Try to learn RigVeda Asura came first and Deva emerged out of them.not from later Hindu scripture which portray  them opposites. By the way there is no secular or communal proof - if I give proof that the cult of pillar among Jews have a parallel in RigVeda  would you call it a secular proof ?

Comment: Sir,can you share the parallel between the pillar cult and Rig Veda? By the way I searched in the net to know about cult of pillar.I couldn't find any. Can you please share any that gives info regarding that.

Comment: @Nadhiya how can you find it on net when no body has written about it? Now I understood what you want. Try  to find the names of RigVedic  gods  like Indra etc on the clay tablets depicting  the treaty between Hittite and Mittani kings of Canaanite region around 1400 BCE. It's available on net. And then try to understand the common features of all ancient cultures surrounding this region, then you'll be able to understand - how the cult of pillar emerged from 'Pillar of Fire & Clouds' and their relation with RigVeda

Comment: Hello Bhaskar Sir, How is the publishing of your book going? I have read few things regarding the clay tablets. If the clay tablets had the name of Indra in it, what is your implication from this?.Does Devas and Asuras refers to group of different people who lived in a common geographical area or do they still refer to specific people?

Comment: Don't forget about the Zoroastrian culture between Bharat and Mesopotamia. They flipped the roles of "ahura" and "daeva." Surely if Ashura refers to the city in Mesopotamia, there must be a good reason for the role reversals East and West of the Sulaiman Mountains

Comment: @ Nadia  I am working for the book on a high pitch, so I am off the exchange now a days. Actually I am working on Rig Veda with different interpretation of its language which comes from the internal analysis of RigVeda itself. In fact Asura and Daeva dichotmy does not exist in RigVeda, it emerges in later scriptures. According to RigVeda Daeva culture emerged as a new waive out of Asura culture particularly after  killing of Vritra by Indra the unsurpassed Daeva of that period. Indra is described as Asura at many times in RigVeda. We shouldn't analyse the ancient from  categories emerge later.

Comment: @RubelliteFae  I am well aware of the presence of Zoroastrian rather ancient Magi of Persia in  between. According  to their own literature they lived along with RigVedic people rather as a part. It was their enemity with sage Angira who drove them out of their original place. They moved to 16 different locations beore finally settling at Iran. Later on Zarthrustra was responding in fact opposing the new religious development in India which he terms as a ' lie'. Indeed in India, there was a major shift from RigVedic position